# Problem installing ecapture due to PEP 517 and can't be installed directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I don't understand why I get this error while trying  to install ecapture using:

```
pip install ecapture
```

#### My System

> Python 3.9.1
>
> Windows 10

#### Error log

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk03ol68y' cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-88owitp7\scikit-image_7518c8b47ede4bae8c7c21f2b3149b68
```

#### Output

**Note:** This is only the last few lines of the output as there are too many lines and they didn't give any errors.

```
  ...
  running build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  building 'skimage._shared.geometry' extension...
  compiling C sources...
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\skimage...
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\skimage\_shared...
  building 'skimage._shared.transform' extension...
  compiling C sources...
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wey_lk16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(20543): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(20548): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(20563): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(20576): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(21715): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(21731): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(22091): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_FromUnicode': deprecated in 3.3
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(23039): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  skimage\_shared\transform.c(23045): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
  error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wey_lk16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wey_lk16\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcskimage\_shared\transform.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\skimage\_shared\transform.obj" failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by downgrading my python to 3.7.0